# При выполнении задачи по отправке sms задача печатается в консоль Celery и не отрабатывает

Tags: django, redis, celery

Вот мой код:

project/__ init __.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery("proj")
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

tasks.py

```
@app.task
def send_sms_prompt_1_hour(order_id):
    order = HelpSession.objects.get(id=order_id)
    text_message = 'Текст сообщения'
    if not order or order.cancel_at:
        return
    sms.send_sms(order.client.phone, text_message)
    return None
```

sms.py

```
def send_sms(phone, msg):
    params = dict(
        login=settings.SMS_LOGIN, psw=settings.SMS_PASSWORD,
        phones=phone, charset='utf-8', mes=msg
    )
    if settings.DEBUG:
        logger.info(f'sending sms {params}')
    else:
        resp = requests.get('example_addres', params)
        if not resp.ok:
            raise Exception(resp.content)
        return resp.content
```

В чем суть ошибки. Сама по себе отправка sms работает, но при вызове функции send_sms через celery, она выдает следующий текст в консоль

```
[31/May/2022 19:25:09,601] sending sms {'login': 'example', 'example': 'example', 'phones': 'example', 'charset': 'utf-8', 'mes': 'example'}
```

example - мой текст, чтобы не показывать конфиденциальную информацию. Вместо него подставляются корректные данные.

Повторю, если вызывать эту функцию НЕ через celery, она работает правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Печатает в консоль потому что `settings.DEBUG == true`. По-этому выполняется все, что внутри условия, а это - `logger.info()`.

Нужно убрать `else:` в функции `send_sms`:

```
def send_sms(phone, msg):
    params = dict(
        login=settings.SMS_LOGIN, psw=settings.SMS_PASSWORD,
        phones=phone, charset='utf-8', mes=msg
    )
    if settings.DEBUG:
        logger.info(f'sending sms {params}')
    else: # Вот эту
        resp = requests.get('example_addres', params)
        if not resp.ok:
            raise Exception(resp.content)
        return resp.content
```

Должно получиться:

```
def send_sms(phone, msg):
    params = dict(
        login=settings.SMS_LOGIN, psw=settings.SMS_PASSWORD,
        phones=phone, charset='utf-8', mes=msg
    )
    if settings.DEBUG:
        logger.info(f'sending sms {params}')
    resp = requests.get('example_addres', params)
    if not resp.ok:
        raise Exception(resp.content)
    return resp.content
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло